# When Firefox will support HTML5 input type=date?

Tags: html, firefox

Because now HTML5 not a draft but recommended standard - strange that Mozilla still not implement that input type.

Comment: I think FF supports it, but it looks damn similar to input type text.

Comment: It doesn't support it (see CanIuse and MDN related docs). What a shame...

Comment: I hate Mozilla for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to know when, you can ask here: [Bug 825294 - Implement date/time input types on Desktop](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=825294).

Also, please, vote for this issue, and write something inspiring to Firefox team.
Hope it will help them to resolve this issue. :)

And now it's seems to be landed in firefox 57 (https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/09/firefox-quantum-developer-edition-fastest-firefox-ever/)

Comment: tsk tsk tsk firefox

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283381 the new task for all date-time related inputs, seems that it will be ready soon

Comment: Yup, it's in 57 (quantum) now!